# Perl Script stops running

Tags: perl

I am trying to get a perl script running (in a Windows cmd window) but it will allways just stop working at a certain point. How can I find out why it will not go on?

Here is the script: The last thing that I can see gets executed is "get_html_source()" in line 37

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Perl script that scrapes the members of the Hellenic Parliament
# Created by Kostas Ntonas, 03 May 2013 - http://ntonas.gr
# http://deixto.blogspot.gr/2013/05/scraping-members-of-greek-parliament.html

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

use IO::File;
use POSIX qw(tmpnam);
use DEiXToBot;
use WWW::Selenium;

my $agent = DEiXToBot->new(); # create the DEiXToBot agent object

# launch a Firefox instance
my $sel = WWW::Selenium->new( host => "localhost",
                              port => 4444,
                              browser => "*firefox",
                              browser_url => "http://www.hellenicparliament.gr/"
                            );
$sel->start;

for my $i (1..30) {

    my $url = "http://www.hellenicparliament.gr/en/Vouleftes/Viografika-Stoicheia?pageNo=$i";

    $sel->open($url);

    $sel->wait_for_page_to_load(5000);

    $sel->pause(1);

    print "$i) $url\n";

    my $content = $sel->get_html_source();

    my ($fh,$name); # create a temporary file containing the page's source code
    do { $name = tmpnam() } until $fh = IO::File->new($name, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL);
    binmode( $fh, ':utf8' );
    print $fh $content;
    close $fh;

    $agent->get("file://$name"); # load the temporary file/page with the DEiXToBot agent using the file:// scheme

    unlink $name; # delete the temporary file, it is not needed any more

    if (! $agent->success) { die "Could not fetch the temp file!\n"; }

    $agent->build_dom();

    $agent->load_pattern('C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Privat\MyCase3\Deixto Patterns\parliament_CVs.xml');

    $agent->extract_content();

    if (! $agent->hits) {
        die "Could not find any MPs/ records!\n";
    }
    else {
        for my $record ($agent->records) {
            my @rec = @$record;

            my $party;
            my $logo = $rec[0];

            # deduce the party name from the logo in the first column of the table
            if ($logo=~m#ND_Logo#) { $party = "N.D. (New Democracy)"; }
            elsif ($logo=~m#COALITION#) { $party = "SYRIZA Unitary Social Front"; }
            elsif ($logo=~m#PASOK#) { $party = "PA.SO.K. (Panhellenic Socialist Movement)"; }
            elsif ($logo=~m#ANEKS_ELL#) { $party = "ANEXARTITOI ELLINES (Independent Hellenes)"; }
            elsif ($logo=~m#xrisi#) { $party = "LAIKOS SYNDESMOS - CHRYSI AVGI (People's Association - Golden Dawn)"; }
            elsif ($logo=~m#small#) { $party = "DHM.AR (Democratic Left)"; }
            elsif ($logo=~m#KKE#) { $party = "K.K.E. (Communist Party of Greece)"; }
            elsif ($logo=~m#INDEPENDENT#) { $party = "INDEPENDENT"; }
            else { die "$logo => Unknown logo!\n"; }

            $rec[0] = $party;

            $rec[3]=~s#\s+# #g; # replace whitespace characters with a single space

            # append the data in a tab delimited text file
            open my $fh,">>:utf8","MPs.txt";
            print $fh join("\t",@rec)."\n";
            close $fh;
        }
    }
}

$sel->stop;
```

Comment: `do { $name = tmpnam(); }` better with semicolon.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. but unfortunatelly this has not changed anything.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that the code is dying inside get_html_source, or is it actually dying immediately before or after (e.g. in the call to tmpnam, which seems to be missing a semi-colon)?

Another comment is that this seems like a lot of work just to scrape the list of MPs and their parties.  If you look at the page source there is a huge block of base-64 encoded text that appears to have all the data you need.  So you might find it quicker to load the page, decode the block and have everything you need.

Comment: @ KingZoingo : you are probably right. But beeing new to programming in general and Perl in particular I would not konw how yet. Do you have a good hint where I start my learnings - for this - best? BTW: I have added the semicolon but no changes. And no I do not know where exactly it is dying. Many thanks.

Comment: You seem confident that it is dying in get_html_source.  To prove this, add a line immediately afterwards that prints something out, e.g. print "I made it this far\n";  If you do not see that, and you see the print shows on line 36, then you have confirmed your theory.  The quickest way beyond that would be to run a network trace from your PC to see if the request is correctly leaving your machine and getting a response from the website.

Answer (score 0):

The tmpnam function is provided by the POSIX Perl module. It should work fine on most variants of Unix/Linux but it seems to be broken under Windows.
I suggest replacing the "problematic" line containing the tmpnam call with the following:

```
use File::Temp qw/ tempfile /;
($fh,$name) = tempfile();
```

Hopefully this change will fix the issue and allow the script to complete.

This is also what the Perl tmpnam documentation (http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html) suggests: "For security reasons, which are probably detailed in your system's documentation for the C library tmpnam() function, this interface should not be used; instead see File::Temp".